# Composite primary key, display entries with one same value and one different

Tags: mysql, sql

This is how my MySQL table looks like : 
[image: SQL Table]

Here, faculty_id and research_area are the primary keys. I want faculties who work in both “AI” and “Big Data”. So Ravi(F1) and Dham(F3) should be printed.

I tried `select * from faculty_details where research_area='AI' AND research_area='Big Data';` and `select * from faculty_details where research_area='AI' or research_area='Big Data';` but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select fd.faculty_id
from faculty_details fd
where fd.research_area in ('AI', 'Big Data')
group by fd.faculty_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

If you can have duplicates, then use:

```
having count(distinct research_area) = 2
```

Comment: This is correct but there must be a better way because if I add one more subject in research area then the count will be different for different faculties.